# Get values to each Label from a Method, which return as a List

Tags: asp.net, linq

I need to get values of ItemCode and ItemName into separate Labels using Linq. I implemented a query joining **tblItem** and **tblInventry**. It returns all rows as a List. Query is below,

```
public tblItem GetItemNameAndCode(int itemID)
{
    var iNameCode = from it in DB.tblItems
                    join inv in DB.tblInventories on it.ItemID equals inv.ItemID
                    where it.ItemID == itemID
                    orderby it.ItemName ascending
                    select it;
    return iNameCode.ToList<tblItem>();
}
```

From the above query(*GetItemNameAndCode(ItemID)*), I need to get ItemCode and ItemName(ascending). That code is below,

```
if (lblItemID != null)
{
      int ItemID = Convert.ToInt32(lblItemID.Text);
      this.ItemBO.Item = this.ItemBO.GetItemNameAndCode(ItemID);
      if (this.ItemBO.Item != null)
      {
          lblItemCode.Text = this.ItemBO.Item.ItemCode;
          lblItemName.Text = this.ItemBO.Item.ItemName;
      }
}
```

But how do I return only those 2 fields ? 
When I use this,

> return iNameCode.ToList();

It gives an exception.
Ultimately I need ItemName get ordered in ascending order.

Comment: `from it in DB.tblItems
                    join inv in DB.tblInventories on it.ItemID equals inv.ItemID
                    where it.ItemID == itemID
                    orderby it.ItemName ascending
                    select it;`
in **select it** do not select full object. you must do it like this 
`select it.itemname , it.itemcode`

Answer (score 1):

it's not very clear if you expect one result or many from the GetItemNameAndCode method, but based on

- the name of the method
- the return type
- the usage afterwards

I presume you actually expect *one* single element having a *code* and a *name* property

In any case i would define an object to hold the return type

```
public class Shape
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and refactor your method to return that one single element from the list

```
public Shape GetItemNameAndCode(int itemID)
{
    var query = from it in DB.tblItems
                join inv in DB.tblInventories on it.ItemID equals inv.ItemID
                where it.ItemID == itemID
                orderby it.ItemName ascending
                select new Shape
                {
                    Code = it.ItemCode,
                    Name = it.ItemName,
                };

    return query.SingleOrDefault();
}
```

notice the *.SingleOrDefault()* at the end

Comment: Actually, I'm a beginner for C#. I earned new knowledge from your answer. Kindly can you explain me, how the object **'shape'**  deals with **'GetItemNameAndCode'** method !

Comment: the shape object is simply put a projection of your query.

Comment: Can u please elaborate it further ?

Comment: the DB.tblItems might have a complex structure on its own, but as you are only interested in returning the Code and the Name, you might as well create a dedicated structure for the return type. Does that make sense?